# What is the status of using Mathematica under the new released windows 11?

Tags: windows

I googled and could not find any information on this.

It is now possible to update from windows 10 to windows 11. I am using windows 10 now.

My question is: Has any one tried say Mathematica 12.3 on windows 11 yet? if so, were there any problems?

Will there be, any official announcement from WRI on if Mathematica will work as is on windows 11? or if there are any issues to worry about before upgrading to windows 11?

Of course, I could call Wolfram support and ask them. But I thought it will be more useful if this information is publicly available so not everyone has to call or email asking the same question.

Comment: The official insider builds are not even out yet.  It will be some time before anyone can say something concrete about it.

Comment: @ihojnicki Ok, thanks. I was reading a post on the net where it was showing how to upgrade to Windows 11 from windows 10. So I assumed one can do that now. In this case, will wait for an official announcement from WRI.

Comment: They were probably showing off the build that was leaked onto the net last week, which I would not recommend doing.  If you would like to try the insider build, you can read up on it at https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/06/24/preparing-for-insider-preview-builds-of-windows-11/.

Comment: I certainly will not say anything about Win11 support until closer to its release date, later this year.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257116/has-anyone-encountered-mathematica-errors-in-the-new-windows-11

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica 12.3.1 works using Windows 11.

Comment: Mind running the benchmark on it and posting? I’d be curious if it is any better/worse than before