# Has anyone encountered Mathematica errors in the new Windows 11?

Tags: windows, upgrade

Obviously, I am referring to code that ran perfectly in Windows 10 but has begun throwing errors in Windows 11.

I have the option of upgrading to Windows 11, but it is critical that my Mathematica code not suddenly start throwing errors. Since I do not want to be the canary in the coal mine, I thought I would ask if someone has already taken that brave step.

Links to resources from Microsoft, Wolfram Research, or third party testers checking compatibility would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/system-requirements.html .  It doesn't mention Windows 11.

Comment: There are guides out there on running Win11 as a virtual machine on Win10. Most are with free virtual machine software and Win11 is free.  With this you can install Mma to the VM and test out your code.

Answer (score 7):

I took the plunge myself. I upgraded to Windows 11 Pro and ran my Mathematica code. There were **no errors**.

Everything seems to be working just as in Windows 10 Pro. Since my code base is quite large, it would appear that Mathematica 12.3.1 runs in Windows 11 just as it does in Windows 10.

Comment: Likewise, I have encountered no Mathematica errors due to Windows 11.

Answer (score 1):

I have had problems with Win11-Pro version 21H2 Build 22000.469 with Mathematica 13.   I'm currently trying to get it to work cleanly.  All initial Mathematica windows that open are blank, no content at all.  On one occasion opening Mathematica directly after a system restart Mathematica worked fine, a usual. I have run a fresh install of Mathematica, and I seem to have the same problem, nothing in the windows.

I am also having some issues with a few applications that are triggering Windows Explorer to  behave oddly, it seems particularly sensitive when HDR is switched on.  Windows 11 - Pro may still have a few issues that need to be resolved.  Explorer seems to get stuck in a loop and take up processor time 4-5%.

My system is an Intel i9 Alienware R5 with 2x 1080Ti+SLI.

Good luck to those that try Windows 11. It will be interesting to keep an eye on this thread to see if others have problems.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/106764)

Comment: @Syed Actually, I think this partially answers the question as the OP apparently just wishes to know whether it is completely safe to upgrade to Windows 11 while it is crucial to have Mathematica working.

Comment: @Guest_Feb22 I think you should report your specific problem to the support, because Windows 11 is officially [supported](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/system-requirements.html) by version 13.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov This is not the experience of WRI devs or they would not have advertised it for Windows 11. I was looking for some specific {problem,solution} pairs. The OP may update the answer if some resolution is achieved later on either by updating this post or by starting a fresh one. Thanks for your feedback; I appreciate it.

Comment: I am having problems with Mathematica 13.2 on Windows 11 Pro. I can set up a manipulate but at times the trajectory under control of the slider bars will either disappear or work erratically. Same thing when I table a function. Sometimes shift enter calculates a set of point pairs as it should. Sometimes the point pairs are completely unrealistic. Tech Support is trying to help. (3 March 23)

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to Windows 11 and am running Mathematica v 13.1.  Everything appeared to be working well until a few days ago when FinancialData stopped working altogether in the front end, just throwing an error message.  I uninstalled MMA and reinstalled, but it didn't fix the problem.

No issues with MMA 13.1 on other Windows 10 machines.

Comment: Sounds like this might best be reported to Wolfram Tech Support!

Comment: I would be highly suspicious that Win11 is behind this. Something else is probably in play here.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

I was encounted with such problems on windows 11.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/111631)

Comment: @bbgodfrey. The poster wants to know some errors about  mathematica on windows 11, and I post one? Where is wrong? 
 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277407/problem-of-resourcedata-in-13-2-on-windows-11. BTW. Context is in the second image.