# Problem of ResourceData in 13.2 on windows 11

Tags: bugs

As Mathematica 13.2 was published, I'm trying it on Windows 11.

I was encounted with such a basic problem.

```
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"];
trainingData = ResourceData[resource, "TrainingData"];
testData = ResourceData[resource, "TestData"];
```

[image]

Question 1 is do you have the same problem?

Question 2 is how to solve it, maybe after adding something to some files, would solve the problem, do you know?

Seems, Mathematica just can't find this file, `CloudObjectLoader`

Additional Testing about Wolfram Engine of 12.3.1 in Windows 11

```
Wolfram Language 12.3.1 Engine for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2021 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= resourceData=ResourceData["MNIST"]

Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[$Failed, CloudObject`Private`BadOption] returned to top level.

Out[1]= Hold[Throw[$Failed, CloudObject`Private`BadOption]]
```

Comment: It works fine for me, I'm running 13.2 on Windows 10. You could try a "clean install" of 13.2: https://support.wolfram.com/12464

Comment: Same here, no problem on my 13.2 W10.